# PostgreSQL: Error in setting the default value for Data type Double

Tags: postgresql, precision, default-value, alter-table

I am having the column with the integer data type and I want to change it to the **DOUBLE PRECISION** with **default value 0.0**.

```
ALTER TABLE public.agents ALTER COLUMN total_number_of_points TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0.0;
```

But above SQL is throwing an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DEFAULT" LINE 1: ...LUMN
>   total_number_of_points TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT 0....

So Postgresql 9+, Is not allowing to set the default value or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `SET` before `DEFAULT`:

```
ALTER TABLE public.agents
ALTER COLUMN total_number_of_points TYPE DOUBLE PRECISION SET DEFAULT 0.0;
```